# How to set width of generated pdf417 barcode using java

Tags: java, pdf417

Hi I am working on generating pdf417 barcode. For this I followed [this](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/java_barcode/barcodes/pdf417.html) link.

```
try { 

             String a = "Microsoft";
             String b = "wkejew";
                PDF417 barcode = new PDF417(); 
                barcode.setData(a+b); 

               // barcode.setData(a);

                ServletOutputStream servletoutputstream = response.getOutputStream(); 

                response.setContentType("image/gif"); 
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 

                barcode.drawBarcode(servletoutputstream);
 } catch (Exception e) { 
                throw new ServletException(e); 
            }
```

so now problem is the barcode I am getting is having much width. So can I decrease the width?

Answer (score 0):

From your [link](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/java_barcode/barcodes/pdf417.html#7):

> How to Set Generated Barcode PDF-417 Image Width and Height?Top
>
> **You can set barcode image width and height through properties barcodeWidth and barcodeHeight values.**
>
> Or you can set X (bar module width) and Y (bar module height) values

Comment: I tried that also. But even I am getting big barcode which is screen width.